# Impedance matching source with tank circuit

Tags: capacitor, impedance-matching, resonance, tank

Is it necessary to impedance match the source (pulsed DC) with the capacitor in a parallel LC tank circuit in order to successfully charge the capacitor and achieve resonance in the tank circuit?

Comment: The higher the source impedance the better. Matching to infinity.

Comment: @Andy aka   Why is that?

Comment: Ask yourself - what is the impedance of a parallel resonant tank circuit.

Comment: I see what you mean. However initially the capacitor will appear as a short circuit to the source.

Comment: Impedance matching is a frequency domain thing and not a time domain thing.